# About Angularjs concepts and references

Tags: angularjs

i'm learning angularjs,but i feel like i'm not going step by step and also the knowledge i'm getting are in pieces,like i'll b on one concept,next concept will have link with some other
I WANT TO BE STRONG IN ANGULAR,
can anyone suggest me something to come out of this problem,it'll help me a lot
Thank you

Comment: check this http://www.ng-newsletter.com/25-days-of-angular

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn angular2, you can use this site:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

I also started learning angular2 from this site before 2 months. You need to know basics of html and javascript before starting this.

Comment: Check these: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/index.htm, these are not for 1.5 but you can learn basics of angular here.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning angular2, I am following https://github.com/mosh-hamedani tutorials. The course is good sequence. I suggest you to follow him or look for his videos if you have enough time.